# suggestions for how to implement a weird VFD jog mode?

Tags: vfd, industrial

I'm a total noob at electronics, but my employer has asked me to try to program a replacement VFD on our industrial stone-cutting saw. Everything works on it now, but I need to figure out how to implement the jog mode that was on the old vfd before it got fried.

As best as I can remember, when we flipped this switch on the control panel, the motor would jog for about two seconds, and then pause for about 20 seconds, then jog again. That would continue automatically until we switched back to the normal mode. There is another dial on the panel that would control the motor speed both in the normal mode and during the two second pulse in the "jog" mode.

Any idea how to implement this back into the new VFD? Unfortunately the old one is totally fried, so I have no point of reference to work from.

As best as i can tell now, that wiring inside was done in a rather unorthodox fashion... there doesn't really seem to be a set of parameters in the advanced manual that really correspond to how it's set up.

I know this is all super-vague, but feel free to ask for any details that I provide for you.

Thanks in advance!

The VFD is a Commander SK from Nidec, and is identical to the original.
PN: 0472-0001-11

Technical data guide: https://inverterdrive.com/file/Commander-SK-Technical-Manual-Data

Comment: Can you provide a make, model and link to the datasheet for the old drive? It may have been programmable and most aren't so you would require a PLC to control the new one. Can you provide capital letters for the start of each sentence. (We know you've got capitals capability because you let a few slip in.) Hit the edit link below your question ...

Comment: Will do, thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Link to something! Make it easy for us!

Comment: Manual at [InverterDrive](https://inverterdrive.com/file/Commander-SK-Technical-Manual-Data). No mention of program capability but there is mention of serial interface.

Answer (score 1):

The advanced manual for your drive is here:

https://inverterdrive.com/file/Commander-SK-Advanced-User-Guide

This drive has the capability of a ladder logic program running in the drive. This is probably how they implemented your unique jog function.

To run a ladder logic program, the drive needs a special memory card called a “LogicStick” that stores the program. Did your old drive have this LogicStick in place? If so, it is entirely possible that the program is still intact on it. Try moving the LogicStick to the new drive.

If the program is not retrievable, then you’ll have to write a new one. It is outside the scope of this site to write that program for you, but if you have any specific questions while you work on it, you can ask them here.